# Can't write to Firebase Database inside of Firebase Storage onSuccess listener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I am trying to store the Firebase storage URL that I get once I upload a file to Firebase Storage, but for reasons I can't understand, I am unable to write to a location on my Firebase database inside of the Storage onSuccess listener. Any ideas why? If this is not the proper way to store the URL location of the uploaded file then what is?

I can't seem to find an example of this. This is for android.
Thank you

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: I store the download URL (and other metadata) of a file in the database all the time. So it must be something specific to your usage. Without seeing the [minimal code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read the link, it's quite useful) it will be hard to say more.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I will be sure to provide some code this evening when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is completely doable, here's an example

```
    StorageReference fileRef = ....;
    Uri fileUri = ....;
    UploadTask uploadTask = fileRef.putFile(fileUri);

    uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
            // Handle unsuccessful uploads
            Log.d("TAG", "onFailure: " + exception);

        }
    }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
       // This is the URL you are looking for, here you should insert it into your db instance...Something like this
         Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

         DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 
         dbRef.child("uploadUrls").child("url1").setValue(downloadUrl.toString());
        }
    });
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Wnieves19, this was helpful. After seeing your comment and Frank van Puffelen's confirmation that what I was trying to do was possible, I did a bit more digging and found the issue (at least I think I did). I was trying to store the Uri as a uri instead of a string. When I tried to store my object into the database, it would cause a stackoverflow! I tried changing it to a string and it seems to work fine.

Comment: What seems a little confusing however is the fact that Firebase allows the storage of user photo url's (which I am able to retreive with user.getPhotoUrl()) and I am able to store those as Uri's, but not the uri from firebase storage. My only guess would be that the Uri's from firebase storage are much longer, therefore the issue. If any of you can shine a bit more insight into that problem that would be great, but I greatly appreciate the help, thank you!

Comment: The issue there is that the getPhotoUrl() method returns a Uri.  Regarding the data types you can save in the realtime database please refer to the read and write data documentation:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Hope this helps

Comment: Oh I just realized i'm not storing any uri's previously. Thanks for the link, I never realized the specific data types that can be saved :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

 uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                Log.d("TAG", "onFailure: " + exception);

            }
        }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
           // This is the URL you are looking for, here you should insert it into your db instance...Something like this
             Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();

            addData(downloadUrl.toString());

            }
        });


public void addData(String downloadUrl)
{

dbRef.child("uploadUrls").child("url1").setValue(downloadUrl);

}
```